# Lebesgue measure and absolutely continuous

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

Let f be a homeomorphism from the real line $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ which maps each null set ( its Lebsegue measure is zero) to a null set. The question is that :
Is $f$ absolutely continuous?

If we strengthen the condition to be that 
$f$ is a quasisymmetric homeomorphism from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ which maps each null set to a null set, then what is the answer?

(addition: for the detail definition of a quasisymmetric map, please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasisymmetric_map)

Comment: To my recollection, the necessary and sufficient condition for a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to be absolutely continuous is to have bounded variation and having the Lusin N property (i.e. mapping null sets to null sets). A homeomorphism is monotone, hence it has bounded variation; so a homeomorphism with the Lusin N property is absolutely continuous. (I'm not posting this as an answer because I haven't looked at this for a while, so I'm not sure if I remember this correctly.)

Comment: @Ian: we also need $f'$ to be integrable.

Comment: @Giovanni Are you sure that doesn't follow from what I've written? The total variation is always at least the integral of the absolute derivative...

Comment: @Ian: of course you are correct, if it has bounded variation then the derivative is integrable. I am concerned about $f(x) = x$: it has bounded variation in every compact set (hence it follows from your reasoning that $f \in AC([a,b])$ for every $a,b$), but is it enough to get $AC(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @Giovanni That's a good point. I assume that we are defining $f \in AC(\mathbb{R})$ to mean two things: first, $\nu (A)=\int_A f'(x) dx$ is a measure on the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ which is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. Second, $f(x)-f(a)=\nu([a,x])$. For $f(x)=x$ this is actually true (this amounts to saying that the Lebesgue measure is absolutely continuous with respect to itself). For $f(x)=x^2$ this is not true, because the integral may be a $\infty - \infty$ form and therefore not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. For each integer $k\ge1$, define $f$ on the interval $[k,k+1)$ to be $f(x) = k+(x-k)^k$. (And define $f(x)=x$ for $x<1$.) Then $f$ is a homeomorphism which maps null sets to null sets, but $f'$ is not bounded where it's defined, hence $f$ is not absolutely continuous.

Comment: It's possible for $f$ to be absolutely continuous on $\mathbb R$ even though $f'$ is unbounded.

Comment: That might be technically true. For this function, for every $M>0$ there exists an open interval on which $f'(x)>M$; that certainly rules out absolute continuity, doesn't it?